# android alertdialog.builder setCursor

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am struggling since hours to get a simple `Alertdialog` populated with a selection from a `SQLLite` database. I am able to verify that the `cursor` actually contains valid data which I am selecting from the `database`, however, the elements are not displayed in the `Alertdialog`. I did tests using `setItems()` or `setAdapter()` using according sample data elements (created programmatically for test purposes) and those lists aren't displayed either. So, it seems I am doing something basic wrong.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivityMain);
alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Manage logbooks");
alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Click logbook for further actions");
alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(true);

final Cursor cursor = mActivityMain.getDatabase().get_table_logbooks_cursor_by_id(0);

alertDialogBuilder.setCursor(cursor, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builderInner = new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivityMain);
        builderInner.setTitle("Your selected Item is");
        builderInner.setMessage(new DatasetLogbook(cursor).getName());
        builderInner.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        builderInner.show();
    }
}, "name");

alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        dialog.cancel();
    }
});

alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        dialog.cancel();
    }
});

final AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: is "name" the name of the Database's column or an arbitrary value ?

Comment: i don't think you can have a message and a cursor at the same time

Comment: name is the DB's columns name. njzk2, you made my day. I had to remove the message. Thx.